# Problem with x filter when trying to filter points according to x value

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to filter points according to its x values. The data may be from a table-formatted text file, or directly typed in coordinates{...}. I tried to use x filter/.code, but for data from text file it seems fine, while the same code yield compiling error if the data are directly typed through coordinates{...}.

```
\addplot[scatter, only marks] table[x=xx, y=yy, col sep=comma]{tmp.txt}; 
% Seems working
```

vs

```
\addplot[scatter, only marks] coordinates{(0,0) (1,1) (1,1.5) (2,2)}; 
%|16 error| Missing = inserted for \ifnum. Y ...s] coordinates{(0,0) (1,1) (1,1.5) (2,2)};
```

I suspect it might be my problematic usage of \pgfmathresult in x filter, but not sure how to fix. The following are the MWE along with the compilation error.
Assuming file tmp.txt is:

```
xx, yy
0,0 
1,1 
1,1.5 
2,2
```

And the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
  x filter/.code= {
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
      \def\pgfmathresult{}
    \fi
 }]
  % This seems working fine
  \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[x=xx, y=yy, col sep=comma]{tmp.txt}; 

  % This cause compilation error, which is
  % |16 error| Missing = inserted for \ifnum. Y ...s] coordinates{(0,0) (1,1) (1,1.5) (2,2)};

  %\addplot[scatter, only marks] coordinates{(0,0) (1,1) (1,1.5) (2,2)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because coordinates are handled via internal floating point representation which is Klingon for me such `1.1Y0.e1` (or something like that) so you see that `Y` in the error message. The solution is to convert it to regular decimal.

Also `\ifnum` works only with integers but pgfmath tends to spit out `1.0` even for integer `1` so better make a dimension comparison to get rid of the complications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   

\pgfplotstableread{
xx yy
0 0
1 1
1 1.5
2 2
}\mytable
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}
\addplot[scatter, only marks,  x filter/.code= {
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
      \def\pgfmathresult{}
    \fi
 }] table[x=xx, y=yy]{\mytable}; 

  \addplot+[no marks,  x filter/.code={
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,verbatim}
\pgfmathprintnumberto{\pgfmathresult}{\mytempvar}
    \ifdim\mytempvar pt=1pt%
      \def\pgfmathresult{}
    \fi
}] coordinates{(0,0) (1,1) (1,1.5) (2,2)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No wonder the "Y" error in my code. By the way, I assume \pgfmathresult refer to this value: \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,verbatim}, which decode numbers like this "1.1Y0.e1". But could you briefly explain \pgfkeys{...} and its parameters here?

Comment: @Causality Actually no. `\pgfmathresult` corresponds to that weird number representation. And `\pgfkeys` sets how the number should be printed after conversion, you can choose for example `sci` instead of `fixed` to print as the scientific output `x 10^z`. If you check the manual of `pgfplotstable` manual these are explained much better than I would do.

Comment: Meanwhile, is it possible to use logical operators in "ifdim" such as "ifdim \myval pt=5pt or \myval pt >8pt"?

Comment: @Causality Yes you can use `>` and `<`.